# How to store list in rows of mysql using Python/Flask?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am getting some values from a html form and I am storing these values to a list. List is like:

```
["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4", "string5"]
```

I want to store these values in rows of mysql but I am confused how to do?

What I did till now is:

```
descrip = []
descrip.append(description1)
descrip.append(description2)
descrip.append(description3)
descrip.append(description4)
descrip.append(description5)

for r in descrp:
    result_descrp = db.execute("""INSERT INTO description(id,description) VALUES (1,%s)""",((descrip))

return render_template('forms/success.html')
```

But I am getting this error:

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: result_descrp = db.execute("""INSERT INTO description(id,description) VALUES (1,%s)""",((descrip))
i think you have to insert "r" not "descrip"

Comment: Thanks @Shiva, That worked.

Comment: update your answer with solution it may help to someone :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
descrip = []
descrip.append(description1)
descrip.append(description2)
descrip.append(description3)
descrip.append(description4)
descrip.append(description5)

for r in range(5):
    if descrip[r]:
        result_add_event = db.execute("""INSERT INTO event_description(event_id,title,description, created_at) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)""",(id,descrip[r],timestamp))
```

This above code worked very fine. :)

Special thanks to [@shiva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3282945/shiva) and also to those who helped me.

Answer (score 0):

At first, You use the placeholder `%s` in the format string which expect a `str`. But you pass a `list` to it.

And I don't know the type of `description` in your schema. If you just want to save the string presentation of list in the database, you can transform list to str with `str(desciption)`.

And `Mysql` also support [json type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) of field.(MariaDB also support json type.)

Comment: MariabDb doesn't support json, it's in process, jira for json support  https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-9056. i just want to share with you :)